# Creating IDs under res/xml

Tags: android, xml, identifier

Part of `res/xml/prompts.xml`:

```
<card
    id="+@id/amytis"
    title="Amytis"
    players="L"
    type="Amytis"
    cost="4" />
```

Then in the code:

```
String id = xml.getAttributeValue(null, "id");
```

I get "+@id/amytis" verbatim.  I expected to get an integer -- an automatically created ID.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know if you can achieve this, because this type of `xml` is not compiled, thus it don't generated an `int`. Try `@+id/amytis` but i don't know if will change the result.

Comment: No -- the attribute still reads "@+id/amytis".

Comment: `+@id` must be a **typo**.

Comment: Nothing changes if I change it to @+id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get "+@id/amytis" verbatim. I expected to get an integer -- an automatically created ID.

No. That is only done on *specific* attributes on *specific* resource types, such as `android:id` on a widget in a `layout` resource. No special processing like this is done on `xml` resources.